# PyQGIS Contour Labelling

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt, qgsvectorlayer

I have generated contours using `gdal:contour` in a pyqgis plugin but am unable to add labels to them. This is the code that I have been trying to get working, but obviously doing something wrong.

```
    layer = iface.activeLayer()

    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "True")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "PT SANS")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "ELEV")
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.Line)
    print(layer.labelsEnabled())

    layer.triggerRepaint()
```

the print statement returns 'False'. The active layer is a contours layer with field 'ELEV'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you will have more success working directly with the `QgsPalLayerSettings` class. The snippet below works for me on a contour layer generated with gdal_contour.

```py
vlayer = iface.activeLayer()
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
txt_format = QgsTextFormat()
txt_format.setFont(QFont('PT SANS'))
txt_format.setSize(10)# default size
settings.setFormat(txt_format)
settings.fieldName = 'ELEV'
settings.drawLabels = True
settings.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)
vlayer.setLabeling(labels)
vlayer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```